# SQLite: Finding top n aggregations for each distinct value in a column

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

Well that wasn't a very clear title, was it?

I have a SQLite table `results`:

```
event   | dayOfWeek | hour| eventCount
--------+-----------+-----+------------
Event A | 0         | 0   | 4926
Event A | 0         | 1   | 1492
...
Event A | 1         | 0   | 7372
Event A | 1         | 1   | 49
...
Event B | 0         | 0   | 234648
...
```

It simply contains the number of time each event occurred at each hour of each day of the week.

I've been building a table `daily` like this:

```
create table daily as
select  event,
        sum(case when dayOfWeek = 0 then count else 0 end) as sunday,
        sum(case when dayOfWeek = 1 then count else 0 end) as monday,
        sum(case when dayOfWeek = 2 then count else 0 end) as tuesday,
        sum(case when dayOfWeek = 3 then count else 0 end) as wednesday,
        sum(case when dayOfWeek = 4 then count else 0 end) as thursday,
        sum(case when dayOfWeek = 5 then count else 0 end) as friday,
        sum(case when dayOfWeek = 6 then count else 0 end) as saturday
from results
group by event;
```

To get a table that looks like this:

```
event   |sunday|monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday
--------+------+------+-------+---------+--------+------+---------
Event A | 345  | 2345 | 341   | 568     | 689    | 2351 | 1455
...
```

Which just contains counts for each event type for each day of the week.  Building a similar table for hour of the day and for day/hour is trivial, and I have both tables available.

I'd like to make a table `topTenPerHour` like this:

```
hour | 1st     | 2nd     | 3rd     | ...
-----+---------+---------+---------+------
0    | Event A | Event C | Event B | ...
1    | Event B | Event D | Event C | ...
...
23   | Event A | Event R | Event D | ...
```

But I'm having trouble seeing how.  Any suggestions?

EDIT: I do not actually need to create a table (I only need to make a SELECT call), so SQLite's restrictions on CREATE TABLE (such as the unavailability of JOIN) do not apply to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have set up your database in an overly complicated way here.

You should have:

- an EventType table which defines each of your events
- an EventLog table which registers each individual event, with "EventTypeId" foreign-key and timestamp.

Everything else you want to do will then be possible using database functions in queries.  Trying to store all of this information in tables is redundant because it already inherently exists in your other tables.  It should be the job of the program accessing your database to call the proper queries instead of the job of the database to save redundant information.

It is usually only a good idea to do this the way you have it set up now if you are making the same query over and over on static data (as in it very rarely updates).  You would use it in that case only because you are worrying about optimizing the runtime of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Alexander! I'm actually working with completely static, historical data. I'm also only creating the table in question one time for use in a report. The database will not be maintained past completion of the project.
In fact, I have the data stored in a layout very similar to your suggestions. I'm just creating intermediate tables for the purpose of presentation and analysis. It's an extremely large database, and having these intermediate tables reduces the runtime of my queries immensely. Do you have any suggestions as to how to produce the table with my current layout?

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen in your other queries, SQL is not really designed to have multiple columns with similar meaning; you end up duplicating much code.

For the top *n* values, we need to compute their rank, which in this case is the number of records that do not hava a smaller event count for the same hour:

```
CREATE VIEW /* or TABLE */ ranks AS
SELECT hour,
       event,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM results
        WHERE hour = hours.hour
          AND eventCount >= hours.eventCount
       ) AS rank
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT event,
                      hour
      FROM results) AS hours
```

We then take the value from the record with a specific rank for each column:

```
SELECT hour,
       (SELECT event FROM ranks WHERE hour = h.hour AND rank = 1) AS "1st",
       (SELECT event FROM ranks WHERE hour = h.hour AND rank = 2) AS "2nd",
       ...
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT hour
      FROM results) AS h
ORDER BY hour
```